# How to send Response of Google forms as a PDF by Email?

Tags: forms, email, pdf, google-docs, google-forms

I want to send the Spreadsheet data of responses as a PDF to someone by Email.

So far, I have checked the existing solutions.

- https://ctrlq.org/code/19869-email-google-spreadsheets-pdf
- http://tjhouston.com/2012/03/merge-info-from-google-forms-to-pdf-document-and-send-via-email/

Above 2 doesnt seem to work. When I initialize those scripts, Google asks for gmail account in a pop-up & after selecting, it gives a security warning.

When I click Proceed, it returns an Error.

Is there any way to achieve this?

I have also tried using an Addon which is not working for me.
[image: Addon Not Found]

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Email Notifications](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/email-notifications-for-f/acknfdkglemcidajjmehljifccmflhkm) addon for Google Forms and it will send a PDF of the form responses to the respondent or any other email address. (disclaimer: I am the author)

Comment: It's not working. See the screenshot of the edited question.

Comment: Strange. The link works for me https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/email-notifications-for-f/acknfdkglemcidajjmehljifccmflhkm

Comment: Is it only available to GSuite customers? 
Can't you use it for regular gmail accounts? 
Because I had similar experience while trying my own scripts.
When I initialize the script, it prompts Security Warning, and when I click on Visit Anyway, it throws _Something went wrong_